# Creating SVG elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am  trying to create some circles in d3js dynamically, But for some reason it fails. My requirement is to show two small circles on the rectangle when I hover the rectangle. on the mouse out event circles should hide. I tried to it by creating a `rect` object and passing it to a function, then in the function I get the group of the rectangle and try to append `circles` to it.

Can anyone tell me where the error is?

```
function drawCircle(rect, side){

        var g = (rect.parentNode);
//                var g = d3.select(aaa.parentNode);
//        console.log(g.attr('id'));


        g.append('rect')
                .attr('x', 10)
                .attr('y', 10)
                .attr('width', 500)
                .attr('height', 500)
                .style('fill', 'red')
        ;

        var x = 0, y = 0, r =0;

        var rectHeight = parseFloat(rect.attr('height'));
        var rectWidth = parseFloat(rect.attr('width'));
        var rectX = parseFloat(rect.attr('x'));
        var rectY = parseFloat(rect.attr('y'));

        y = rectY + rectHeight/2;
        r  = rectHeight/8;

        if(side == 'left'){
            x = rectX;
        }else{
            x = rectX + rectWidth;
        }

        g.append('circle')
                .attr('cx', x)
                .attr('cy', y)
                .attr('r', r)
                .style('visibility', 'hidden')
                .on('mouseover', function(){
                   g
                            .selectAll('circle')
                            .style('visibility', 'visible')
                    ;
                })
                .on('mouseout', function () {
                    g
                            .selectAll('circle')
                            .style('visibility', 'hidden')
                });

        rect
                .on('mouseover', function(){

//                    alert('hover');

                    g
                            .selectAll('circle')
                            .style('visibility', 'visible')
                    ;
                })
                .on('mouseout', function(){
                   g
                            .selectAll('circle')
                            .style('visibility', 'hidden')

                })




    }




 var rectangle = {
        width : 50,
        height:50,
        x:100,
        y:100

    }; 

   var svg = d3.select('svg');

    var g = svg.append('g').attr('id', 'group');

    console.log(g.attr('id'));

    var rect = g.append('rect')
                    .attr('id', 'aaa')
            .attr('x', rectangle.x)
            .attr('y', rectangle.y)
            .attr('width', rectangle.width)
            .attr('height', rectangle.height)
            .style('fill', 'blue')
            .on('mouseover', function(){

                    drawCircle(this, 'right');
                    drawCircle(this, 'left');
                        })

     ;
```

Comment: Sorry. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fawzan/4a17z1pn/

Comment: Remember in JSfiddle, you have to add the link to D3 as an external resource... Fortunately there is a Content Distribution Network (CDN) available for that library...   https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js

Comment: error:  `Uncaught TypeError:  g.append is not a function`?

Comment: yes, That is what confused me. How can I aces the parent node from the function?

Comment: I'd start by cleaning up the code a bit.. get indents cleaned up, use a different var name for g inside the function (g is both a 'global' and 'local' variable... change the name of one of them to make troubleshooting easier...)

Comment: agree, but I have declared 'g' inside the function. No confusion there. anyway I will change it.

Comment: I've been dinking with this for 30 minutes now.  d3 elements seem to be arrays, but parent elements are dom objects.  `g  = (rect.parentNode);` Not sure how to correct this?  I've added a bunch of `console.log(g);` callouts.  Can I get the URL for your updated jsfiddle, so we're on the same page?

Comment: Thanks for the effort zipzit. @Roberts solution works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert's Answer worked fine. But I have found another solution. I think this is more elegant than that.

```
function drawCircle(rect, side){

    var g = d3.select(rect.node().parentNode);

    var x = 0, y = 0, r =0;

    var rectHeight = parseFloat(rect.attr('height'));
    var rectWidth = parseFloat(rect.attr('width'));
    var rectX = parseFloat(rect.attr('x'));
    var rectY = parseFloat(rect.attr('y'));

    y = rectY + rectHeight/2;
    r  = rectHeight/8;

    if(side == 'left'){
        x = rectX;
    }else{
        x = rectX + rectWidth;
    }

    g.append('circle')
            .attr('cx', x)
            .attr('cy', y)
            .attr('r', r)
            .style('visibility', 'hidden')
            .on('mouseover', function(){
               g
                        .selectAll('circle')
                        .style('visibility', 'visible')
                ;
            })
            .on('mouseout', function () {
                g
                        .selectAll('circle')
                        .style('visibility', 'hidden')
            });

    rect
            .on('mouseover', function(){
                g
                        .selectAll('circle')
                        .style('visibility', 'visible')
                ;
            })
            .on('mouseout', function(){
               g
                        .selectAll('circle')
                        .style('visibility', 'hidden')

            })




}

var rectangle = {
    width : 50,
    height:50,
    x:100,
    y:100

}; 

var svg = d3.select('svg');

var g = svg.append('g').attr('id', 'group');

console.log(g.attr('id'));

var rect = g.append('rect')
                .attr('id', 'aaa')
        .attr('x', rectangle.x)
        .attr('y', rectangle.y)
        .attr('width', rectangle.width)
        .attr('height', rectangle.height)
        .style('fill', 'blue')
        .on('mouseover', function(){

                drawCircle(rect, 'right');
                drawCircle(rect, 'left');
                    })

 ;
```

Answer (score 3):

You want something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/4a17z1pn/10/)?

[0][0] gives you the underlying DOM element if you have a d3 selection. I also removed the big red test rect as that stopped everything working.

```
function drawCircle(rect, side){

    var g = d3.select(rect[0][0].parentNode);

    var x = 0, y = 0, r =0;

    var rectHeight = parseFloat(rect.attr('height'));
    var rectWidth = parseFloat(rect.attr('width'));
    var rectX = parseFloat(rect.attr('x'));
    var rectY = parseFloat(rect.attr('y'));

    y = rectY + rectHeight/2;
    r  = rectHeight/8;

    if(side == 'left'){
        x = rectX;
    }else{
        x = rectX + rectWidth;
    }

    g.append('circle')
            .attr('cx', x)
            .attr('cy', y)
            .attr('r', r)
            .style('visibility', 'hidden')
            .on('mouseover', function(){
               g
                        .selectAll('circle')
                        .style('visibility', 'visible')
                ;
            })
            .on('mouseout', function () {
                g
                        .selectAll('circle')
                        .style('visibility', 'hidden')
            });

    rect
            .on('mouseover', function(){
                g
                        .selectAll('circle')
                        .style('visibility', 'visible')
                ;
            })
            .on('mouseout', function(){
               g
                        .selectAll('circle')
                        .style('visibility', 'hidden')

            })




}

var rectangle = {
    width : 50,
    height:50,
    x:100,
    y:100

}; 

var svg = d3.select('svg');

var g = svg.append('g').attr('id', 'group');

console.log(g.attr('id'));

var rect = g.append('rect')
                .attr('id', 'aaa')
        .attr('x', rectangle.x)
        .attr('y', rectangle.y)
        .attr('width', rectangle.width)
        .attr('height', rectangle.height)
        .style('fill', 'blue')
        .on('mouseover', function(){

                drawCircle(rect, 'right');
                drawCircle(rect, 'left');
                    })

 ;
```

Comment: Thanks man. It works great. Thanks for the pointer rect[0][0].parentNode . That was the exact same place I struggled .

Comment: Hi, I found an elegant way, Checkout my answer. :)